# Running a .sql script using MySQL with JDBC

Tags: java, sql, mysql, jdbc

I am starting to use MySQL with JDBC.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:///x", "x", "x");
stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.execute( "CREATE TABLE amigos" +
            "("+
            "id          int AUTO_INCREMENT          not null,"+
            "nombre      char(20)                    not null,"+
            "primary key(id)" +
            ")");
```

I have 3-4 tables to create and this doesn't look good.

Is there a way to run a .sql script from MySQL JDBC?

Comment: any particular reason why you need to write java code to run these create table statements? Are they dynamic in some way?

Comment: because he wants to do all stuff by Java xD

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Ok. You can use this class here (posted on pastebin because of file length) in your project. But remember to keep the apache license info.

[JDBC ScriptRunner](https://github.com/BenoitDuffez/ScriptRunner)

It's ripoff of the iBatis ScriptRunner with dependencies removed.

You can use it like this

```
Connection con = ....
ScriptRunner runner = new ScriptRunner(con, [booleanAutoCommit], [booleanStopOnerror]);
runner.runScript(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.sql")));
```

That's it!

Comment: Very handful class. I must add that line 130 can cause headaches. I replaced it to "String trimmedLine = line.trim().replaceAll(";$", Matcher.quoteReplacement("; \\"));" because you might get http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499483/error-unterminated-quoted-string-at-or-near

Comment: Can this be used to return a `ResultSet` or it only works for update statements? I tried using it but cannot figure how to get it to return a `ResultSet`. I would go for `Spring` but it is easier to use a class than an entire library.

Comment: be careful with the linked to script a bit--if your script has a code "comment" like `select 1; -- do nothing` then the script doesn't execute it but treats it like the first half of a longer command [concatenated with the new command] other side effect--if that's the last thing in your file, it doesn't run it at all].  If you just stick with single line sql comments it's ok

Comment: this class can't handle PROCEDURE ever

Comment: Does not work when creating procedures that utilize DELIMITER and END

Comment: I took the liberty to copy the code, update it to add support for delimiters for stored procedures, upload it to GitHub, and update the link in @jitter's answer.

Answer (score 26):

I did a lot of research on this and found a good [util from spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/jdbc/JdbcTestUtils.html#executeSqlScript%28org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate,%20org.springframework.core.io.Resource,%20boolean%29). I think using `SimpleJdbcTestUtils.executeSqlScript(...)` is actually the best solution, as it is more maintained and tested.

Edit: `SimpleJdbcTestUtils` is deprecated. You should use `JdbcTestUtils`. Updated the link.

Comment: Thanks @Amir Raminfar, your answer helped me out. Anyway just as an update, spring deprecated `SimpleJdbcTestUtil` and advises to use `JdbcTestUtils` in future.

Comment: This is the best answer, the Spring framework team is active.

Comment: Starting from Spring 4.0.3. `JdbcTestUtils.executeSqlScript()` methods are now deprecated. `ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(...)` should be used instead.

Comment: Please note that, actively developed or not, those utility classes were designed with testing in mind, and won't be sufficient for most cases; for example, they won't allow you to create a stored procedure due to delimiter problems; [joe776's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5029925/679240) may be a better option, depending on your need,

Answer (score 17):

Spring Framework's `ResourceDatabasePopulator` may help. As you said you're using MySQL and JDBC,  let's assume you have a MySQL-backed `DataSource` instance ready. Further, let's assume your MySQL script files are classpath-locatable. Let's assume you are using WAR layout and the script files are located in a directory `src/main/webapp/resources/mysql-scripts/...` or `src/test/resources/mysql-scripts/...`. Then you can use `ResourceDatabasePopulator` to execute SQL scripts like this:

```
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

DataSource dataSource = getYourMySQLDriverBackedDataSource();

ResourceDatabasePopulator rdp = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();    
rdp.addScript(new ClassPathResource(
                        "mysql-scripts/firstScript.sql"));
rdp.addScript(new ClassPathResource(
                        "mysql-scripts/secondScript.sql"));

try {
        Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        rdp.populate(connection); // this starts the script execution, in the order as added
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: By far the best answer here.  I get tired of seeing the answers that tell you to run the MySQL dump import from the command line.  Doesn't work so well in an automated environment where the database is on a different server.

Comment: @Zoidberg The `mysql` command line client and `mysqldump` work fine over a network and can be used in automated scripts. Having the database on a different server should pose no issue.

Comment: @Asaph You are correct.  I actually tried the above solution and found the performance was really slow.  I got it working with the command line argument just fine, so my above comment is actually incorrect.

Answer (score 6):

For simple sql script splitted by ';' you can use this simple function.
It remove comments and run statements one by one

```
  static void executeScript(Connection conn, InputStream in)
    throws SQLException
  {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(in);
    s.useDelimiter("/\\*[\\s\\S]*?\\*/|--[^\\r\\n]*|;");

    Statement st = null;

    try
    {
      st = conn.createStatement();

      while (s.hasNext())
      {
        String line = s.next().trim();

        if (!line.isEmpty())
          st.execute(line);
      }
    }
    finally
    {
      if (st != null)
        st.close();
    }
  }
```

Comment: You are assuming that comments can't appear inside of a single statement. In CREATE TABLE this is common.

Comment: I will say even more. It does not support complex queries, but you can change delimeter to something else like ';[\s\r\n]*\\'. and use comments as you like.

Comment: sorry but this one work better http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497569/how-to-execute-sql-script-file-using-jdbc/1498029#1498029

Comment: Atais, glad to see your attemps... my code is just an example, use it you wish :)

Answer (score 5):

@Pantelis Sopasakis

Slightly modified version on GitHub: https://gist.github.com/831762/

Its easier to track modifications there.

Comment: After fixing the bug in the comment on this gist, this appears to work so far!

Answer (score 2):

Regarding SQL script runner (which I'm also using), I noticed the following piece of code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
  String value = rs.getString(i);
  print(value + "\t");
}
```

However, in the API documentation for the method getString(int) it's mentioned that [indexes start with 1](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString%28int%29), so this should become:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= cols; i++) {
  String value = rs.getString(i);
  print(value + "\t");
}
```

Second, this implementation of ScriptRunner does not provide support for **DELIMITER** statements in the SQL script which are important if you need to compile TRIGGERS or PROCEDURES. So I have created this modified version of ScriptRunner: http://pastebin.com/ZrUcDjSx which I hope you'll find useful.

Answer (score 2):

Another interesting option would be to use [Jisql](https://www.xigole.com/software/jisql/jisql.jsp;jsessionid=4BAA16D41278CED2DAA2FFD3C0277096) to run the scripts. Since the source code is available, it should be possible to embed it into an application.

---

Edit: took a careful look at it; embedding it inside something else would require some modification to its source code.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use this:

```
public static void executeSQL(File f, Connection c) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    String sql = "", line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) sql += (line+"\n");
    c.prepareCall(sql).execute(sql);
}
```

This function gets SQL file and DB connection.
Then it reads the file line-by-line using BufferedReader from java.io.
And, finally, executes the read statements.

Java 8+ version:

```
public static void executeSQL(Path p, Connection c) throws Exception {
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(p);
    String s = String.join("\n", lines.toArray(new String[0]));
    c.prepareCall(s).execute(s);
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.

Answer (score 1):

Write code to:

1. Read in a file containing a number of SQL statements.
2. Run each SQL statement.

Comment: If I do it like that I should parse the .sql file. I was expecting there was a jdbc's fuction which I couldn't find.

Answer (score 1):

For Oracle PL/SQL, the Oracle JDBC-driver indeed supports executing entire SQL-scripts including stored procedures and anonymous blocks (PL/SQL specific notation), see

[Can the JDBC Drivers access PL/SQL Stored Procedures?](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/java/sqlj_jdbc/htdocs/jdbc_faq.html#34_01)

The [Oracle JDBC driver FAQ](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B13789_01/java.101/b10979/basic.htm#sthref307) has more info:

> Oracle JDBC drivers support execution
>   of PL/SQL stored procedures and
>   anonymous blocks. They support both
>   SQL92 escape syntax and Oracle PL/SQL
>   block syntax. The following PL/SQL
>   calls would work with any Oracle JDBC
>   driver:

```
// SQL92 syntax
CallableStatement cs1 = conn.prepareCall
                       ( "{call proc (?,?)}" ) ; // stored proc
CallableStatement cs2 = conn.prepareCall
                       ( "{? = call func (?,?)}" ) ; // stored func
// Oracle PL/SQL block syntax
CallableStatement cs3 = conn.prepareCall
                       ( "begin proc (?,?); end;" ) ; // stored proc
CallableStatement cs4 = conn.prepareCall
                       ( "begin ? := func(?,?); end;" ) ; // stored func
```

It should be possible to read in a file and feed the content to the prepareCall()-method.

Comment: The first link to the question is broken.

Answer (score 1):

[Maven SQL Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/sql-maven-plugin/)  Use this plugin to execute SQL statements a file or  list of files through

1. sqlCommand
2. srcFiles
   3.fileset configurations

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a way to do this.

You could either run the mysql command line client via Runtime.exec(String[]) and read [this article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html) when you decide for this option

Or try using the ScriptRunner (com.ibatis.common.jdbc.ScriptRunner) from [ibatis](http://ibatis.apache.org/). But it's a bit stupid to include a whole library just to run a script.

Comment: Yes, it's true. Doesn't make sense to add a lib just to run a script :(
I think it's quite strange that jdbc doesn't come with something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty solution that worked for me.

```
public void executeScript(File scriptFile) {
  Connection connection = null;
  try {
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    if(scriptFile.exists()) {
      var buffer = new StringBuilder();
      var scanner = new Scanner(scriptFile);
      while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        var line = scanner.nextLine();
        buffer.append(line);
        // If we encounter a semicolon, then that's a complete statement, so run it.
        if(line.endsWith(";")) {
          String command = buffer.toString();
          connection.createStatement().execute(command);
          buffer = new StringBuilder();
        } else { // Otherwise, just append a newline and keep scanning the file.
          buffer.append("\n");
        }
     }
    }
    else System.err.println("File not found.");
  } catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  if(connection != null) connection.close();
}
```