# How to execute .sql script file using JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Running a .sql script using MySQL with JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044194/running-a-sql-script-using-mysql-with-jdbc)

I have an SQL script file which contains 40-50 SQL statements. Is it possible to run this script file using JDBC?

Answer (score 35):

This link might help you out: http://pastebin.com/f10584951.

Pasted below for posterity:

```
/*
 * Slightly modified version of the com.ibatis.common.jdbc.ScriptRunner class
 * from the iBATIS Apache project. Only removed dependency on Resource class
 * and a constructor
 */
/*
 *  Copyright 2004 Clinton Begin
 *
 *  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 *  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 *  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 *  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 *  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 *  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 *  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 *  limitations under the License.
 */

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.LineNumberReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.sql.*;

/**
 * Tool to run database scripts
 */
public class ScriptRunner {

    private static final String DEFAULT_DELIMITER = ";";

    private Connection connection;

    private boolean stopOnError;
    private boolean autoCommit;

    private PrintWriter logWriter = new PrintWriter(System.out);
    private PrintWriter errorLogWriter = new PrintWriter(System.err);

    private String delimiter = DEFAULT_DELIMITER;
    private boolean fullLineDelimiter = false;

    /**
     * Default constructor
     */
    public ScriptRunner(Connection connection, boolean autoCommit,
            boolean stopOnError) {
        this.connection = connection;
        this.autoCommit = autoCommit;
        this.stopOnError = stopOnError;
    }

    public void setDelimiter(String delimiter, boolean fullLineDelimiter) {
        this.delimiter = delimiter;
        this.fullLineDelimiter = fullLineDelimiter;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for logWriter property
     *
     * @param logWriter
     *            - the new value of the logWriter property
     */
    public void setLogWriter(PrintWriter logWriter) {
        this.logWriter = logWriter;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for errorLogWriter property
     *
     * @param errorLogWriter
     *            - the new value of the errorLogWriter property
     */
    public void setErrorLogWriter(PrintWriter errorLogWriter) {
        this.errorLogWriter = errorLogWriter;
    }

    /**
     * Runs an SQL script (read in using the Reader parameter)
     *
     * @param reader
     *            - the source of the script
     */
    public void runScript(Reader reader) throws IOException, SQLException {
        try {
            boolean originalAutoCommit = connection.getAutoCommit();
            try {
                if (originalAutoCommit != this.autoCommit) {
                    connection.setAutoCommit(this.autoCommit);
                }
                runScript(connection, reader);
            } finally {
                connection.setAutoCommit(originalAutoCommit);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error running script.  Cause: " + e, e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Runs an SQL script (read in using the Reader parameter) using the
     * connection passed in
     *
     * @param conn
     *            - the connection to use for the script
     * @param reader
     *            - the source of the script
     * @throws SQLException
     *             if any SQL errors occur
     * @throws IOException
     *             if there is an error reading from the Reader
     */
    private void runScript(Connection conn, Reader reader) throws IOException,
            SQLException {
        StringBuffer command = null;
        try {
            LineNumberReader lineReader = new LineNumberReader(reader);
            String line = null;
            while ((line = lineReader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (command == null) {
                    command = new StringBuffer();
                }
                String trimmedLine = line.trim();
                if (trimmedLine.startsWith("--")) {
                    println(trimmedLine);
                } else if (trimmedLine.length() < 1
                        || trimmedLine.startsWith("//")) {
                    // Do nothing
                } else if (trimmedLine.length() < 1
                        || trimmedLine.startsWith("--")) {
                    // Do nothing
                } else if (!fullLineDelimiter
                        && trimmedLine.endsWith(getDelimiter())
                        || fullLineDelimiter
                        && trimmedLine.equals(getDelimiter())) {
                    command.append(line.substring(0, line
                            .lastIndexOf(getDelimiter())));
                    command.append(" ");
                    Statement statement = conn.createStatement();

                    println(command);

                    boolean hasResults = false;
                    if (stopOnError) {
                        hasResults = statement.execute(command.toString());
                    } else {
                        try {
                            statement.execute(command.toString());
                        } catch (SQLException e) {
                            e.fillInStackTrace();
                            printlnError("Error executing: " + command);
                            printlnError(e);
                        }
                    }

                    if (autoCommit && !conn.getAutoCommit()) {
                        conn.commit();
                    }

                    ResultSet rs = statement.getResultSet();
                    if (hasResults && rs != null) {
                        ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
                        int cols = md.getColumnCount();
                        for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
                            String name = md.getColumnLabel(i);
                            print(name + "\t");
                        }
                        println("");
                        while (rs.next()) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
                                String value = rs.getString(i);
                                print(value + "\t");
                            }
                            println("");
                        }
                    }

                    command = null;
                    try {
                        statement.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // Ignore to workaround a bug in Jakarta DBCP
                    }
                    Thread.yield();
                } else {
                    command.append(line);
                    command.append(" ");
                }
            }
            if (!autoCommit) {
                conn.commit();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.fillInStackTrace();
            printlnError("Error executing: " + command);
            printlnError(e);
            throw e;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.fillInStackTrace();
            printlnError("Error executing: " + command);
            printlnError(e);
            throw e;
        } finally {
            conn.rollback();
            flush();
        }
    }

    private String getDelimiter() {
        return delimiter;
    }

    private void print(Object o) {
        if (logWriter != null) {
            System.out.print(o);
        }
    }

    private void println(Object o) {
        if (logWriter != null) {
            logWriter.println(o);
        }
    }

    private void printlnError(Object o) {
        if (errorLogWriter != null) {
            errorLogWriter.println(o);
        }
    }

    private void flush() {
        if (logWriter != null) {
            logWriter.flush();
        }
        if (errorLogWriter != null) {
            errorLogWriter.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution is usefull for basic things only. For example if you're having a simple set of select/update/insert statements only etc. But if you'll try to create a stored procedure in such way... It'll fail.

Comment: According to Shafi, he is having '40-50 sql statements' that means he is not having SP in his SQL script. :)

Comment: Since I'm already using Mybatis, it was great to just make things work.

Comment: Isn't this slightly broken?  `ResultSet` uses 1-based column indexes, but this is using 0-based.

Comment: Its giving me an error at this line - command.append(line.substring(0, line
                            .lastIndexOf(getDelimiter()))); Its a complie time error. The error is this - The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Comment: fails with `DELIMITER $ CREATE PROCEDURE`

Comment: What if it is a dump mysql file with comments, create tables, procedures? Every line is executed and works for comments, but for ddl which have several lines, we need to use Callablestatement

Comment: There is an extended version (from 2019) of the ScriptRunner class available here: https://github.com/BenoitDuffez/ScriptRunner/blob/master/ScriptRunner.java

Answer (score 23):

I use this bit of code to import sql statements created by mysqldump:

```
public static void importSQL(Connection conn, InputStream in) throws SQLException
{
    Scanner s = new Scanner(in);
    s.useDelimiter("(;(\r)?\n)|(--\n)");
    Statement st = null;
    try
    {
        st = conn.createStatement();
        while (s.hasNext())
        {
            String line = s.next();
            if (line.startsWith("/*!") && line.endsWith("*/"))
            {
                int i = line.indexOf(' ');
                line = line.substring(i + 1, line.length() - " */".length());
            }

            if (line.trim().length() > 0)
            {
                st.execute(line);
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (st != null) st.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you need to create a statement (conn.createStatement()) for every line?

Comment: I use `s.useDelimiter("(;(\r)?\n)|((\r)?\n)?(--)?.*(--(\r)?\n)");`

Answer (score 10):

Another option, this DOESN'T support comments, very useful with AmaterasERD DDL export for Apache Derby:

```
public void executeSqlScript(Connection conn, File inputFile) {

    // Delimiter
    String delimiter = ";";

    // Create scanner
    Scanner scanner;
    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(inputFile).useDelimiter(delimiter);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    // Loop through the SQL file statements 
    Statement currentStatement = null;
    while(scanner.hasNext()) {

        // Get statement 
        String rawStatement = scanner.next() + delimiter;
        try {
            // Execute statement
            currentStatement = conn.createStatement();
            currentStatement.execute(rawStatement);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // Release resources
            if (currentStatement != null) {
                try {
                    currentStatement.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            currentStatement = null;
        }
    }
scanner.close();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just read it and then use the preparedstatement with the full sql-file in it.

(If I remember good)

**ADD:** You can also read and split on `";"` and than execute them all in a loop.
Do not forget the comments and add again the `";"`

Comment: It did not work. Error thrown for ";" which presents at the end of each sql statement.

Comment: then remove the semi-colon - prepared statements probably doesnt take delimiters.

Comment: Upvote for the split tip!

Comment: What if one of your strings contains ; ?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to parse the SQL file into statements. And run a single statement a time. If you know that your file consists of simple insert/update/delete statements you can use a semicolon as statement delimiter. In common case you have a task to create your specific SQL-dialect parser.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem trying to execute an SQL script that creates an SQL database. Googling here and there I found a Java class initially written by Clinton Begin which supports comments (see http://pastebin.com/P14HsYAG). I modified slightly the file to cater for triggers where one has to change the default DELIMITER to something different. I've used that version ScriptRunner (see http://pastebin.com/sb4bMbVv). Since an (open source and free) SQLScriptRunner class is an absolutely necessary utility, it would be good to have some more input from developers and hopefully we'll have soon a more stable version of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the script line per line with a `BufferedReader` and append every line to a `StringBuilder` so that the script becomes one large string.

Then you can create a `Statement` object using JDBC and call `statement.execute(stringBuilder.toString())`.

Comment: .execute throws an error if string has more the one line. You need to execute line by line as previous answers showed