# creating procedure/tables from java files

Tags: java, sql

i am having the script of tables in normal txt files also i have scripts for procedures and functions. Now, i want to just read that file from java and i want op fire that string (script) on DB.. is it possible..
i have written statements for all DML queries, but here i want to use DDL queries from Java.. can any one help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497569/how-to-execute-sql-script-file-using-jdbc) is question is very similar to what you are asking.

Have also a look at iBatis [ScriptRunner](http://ibatis.apache.org/docs/java/user/com/ibatis/common/jdbc/ScriptRunner.html).

Answer (score 0):

Read the script with a BufferedReader (see [some examples](http://www.devdaily.com/java/java-bufferedreader-readline-string-examples)) appending each line to a StringBuilder. Then use JDBC to create Statement and call execute on it, with your stringbuilder object as a string argument.

```
//create StringBuilder "myProc" here, reading the script
//get Connection conn
//...
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate(myProc);
```

Check the J[ava Tutorial lesson on SQL Statements for Creating a Stored Procedure](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sql.html).

You need to handle delimiters and iterate over the script with this idea if your file contains more than one script.