# How import and export .sql

Tags: java, sql

**How import and export .sql file by query. 
notice Using in jdbc**

Comment: Are you asking about creating and loading an SQL dump file?  If so, then the simple way is to use the database's sql dump / restore utilities, not JDBC.  Just call it using the `Process` class.

Comment: I want to store my data in my drive D or E by java app .
I'm afraid of losing my data

Comment: And I have not more experience in Sql to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The importing part of your question has already been asked here "[How to execute .sql script file using JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497569/how-to-execute-sql-script-file-using-jdbc)"

To do exporting you need to create a SQL queries to get data from every table in your database. Then write that data out to a file.

Your task of exporting data would be more simple using sql dump utilities, or MYSQL workbench.

Do export a single database via command line you can do this:

$ mysqldump -u [uname] -p[pass] db_name > db_backup.sql

More command line options for SQL can be found here: "[MySQL: How to export and import an .sql file from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407349/mysql-how-to-export-and-import-an-sql-file-from-command-line)"

Comment: I want to export and import my data by statement (jdbc)

Comment: What statement? There are no single statements in java to do that.

Comment: Work only in CMD ?? 
$ mysqldump -u [uname] -p[pass] db_name > db_backup.sql

Comment: @AmrEmaish - That is correct ... though you can run that using `java.lang.Process` via a BAT or shell script.

Comment: @Stephen C - thanks , I'm trying :)