# JUnit 4 & Spring Boot - selectively reload context/reload Spring Security configuration before test

Tags: spring-boot, junit, spring-security, junit4, applicationcontext

I use the SpringJUnit4ClassRunner to run integration tests for a Spring Boot application.

During my search I found out it is possible to reload the app context with @DirtiesContext.

My issue: I only need to reload the security configuration (which depends on a DB entry), while keeping the rest as is (or to be precise: I need to keep the H2 database as is).

How to only reload the security configuration before a JUnit test?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to keep H2 Database as it is, you might consider setting the property `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` to `update`, because it will create the database if doesn't exists and will keep it the existing if exists. If you have already have a `application-test.properties` you can create another properties like `application-securityTest.properties`.

```
#... Your DB connection info
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Then in your test class you need to activate this profile with the annotation `@ActiveProfiles` and use the `@DirtiesContext` to reload Spring context:

```
@ActiveProfiles("securityTest")
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class SecurityTest { ... }
```

Comment: I am using Liquibase, forgot to mention.

Or another approach: how to insert data (it is only one record which is needed for the startup of the Boot application) into the DB before Spring Boot starts loading the application context?

Comment: You can do this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html or you can write an SQL script with your insert statement and execute it (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1497614/4857050) before the test execution

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem another way, I modified the implemention so that the security configuration can variably be modified during runtime and doesn't require the DB entry at startup.