# Importing a (mysql) database dump programmatically through Java

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

How can I import a mysql database dump file (contains insert and create table statements) programmatically through a java program. I need this as the setup phase of a unit test.

Unfortunately this doesn't work:

```
Connection conn = dbConnectionSource.getConnection();
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.execute(FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("./some-sql-file")));
conn.close();
```

Thanks,
-A

PS - In Rails, I used fixtures for filling a test database. I made rails rails create the underlying tables through setting the environment to test, anything similar in Java.

Comment: "pragmatically" should be "programmatically"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could start a new process from java and execute this command if you have access to the mysql executable wherever you are running the import. Something like this:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("mysql -p -h ServerName DbName < dump.sql");
```

Comment: This is the *right* way to do this. Any other way may fail to work in subtle edge-cases. Mysql dumps are written to be imported with the mysql client, not any other tool.

Comment: Just a fix, we cant use redirection like that in java:

Process pr = rt.exec(new String[]{"/bin/bash","-c","mysql -p -h ServerName DbName < dump.sql"});

Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: any ideas on how to do this in Windows?

Answer (score 5):

Backup:

```
/******************************************************/
//Database Properties
/******************************************************/
String dbName = “dbName”;
String dbUser = “dbUser”;
String dbPass = “dbPass”;

/***********************************************************/
// Execute Shell Command
/***********************************************************/
String executeCmd = “”;
executeCmd = “mysqldump -u “+dbUser+” -p”+dbPass+” “+dbName+” -r backup.sql”;
}
Process runtimeProcess =Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();
if(processComplete == 0){

out.println(“Backup taken successfully”);

} else {

out.println(“Could not take mysql backup”);

}
```

Restore:

```
/******************************************************/
//Database Properties
/******************************************************/
String dbName = “dbName”;
String dbUser = “dbUser”;
String dbPass = “dbPass”;

/***********************************************************/
// Execute Shell Command
/***********************************************************/
String executeCmd = “”;

executeCmd = new String[]{“/bin/sh”, “-c”, “mysql -u” + dbUser+ ” -p”+dbPass+” ” + dbName+ ” < backup.sql” };

}
Process runtimeProcess =Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();
if(processComplete == 0){

out.println(“success”);

} else {

out.println(“restore failure”);

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Personally I would disrecommend loading a regular SQL dump in this way, because you would need non-trivial code to parse or at least tokenize SQL.

I would recommend using CSV data dumps, you can load these with a the LOAD DATA INFILE syntax. See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Of course, you would still need to ensure the target tables exist, but if you know you only have to parse table creation DDL stattemnts, that will drastically simplify your java code.

Note that you can use mysqldump to extract CSV data from your database, see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_tab

Comment: don't they have the library for import / exporting mysql in java?

Answer (score 0):

Effective solution can be found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1044837

This explains how to run any sql script over jdbc.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a bit old, but I think people are still looking for an answer like me.

Basically, I wanted to make two buttons in my GUI (one to import, and the other to export) and generate an SQL file, I tested the chosen solution to start a process from java and execute it with Runtime but it didn't work, I had an *Access Denied* error eventhought I am the only user in my computer. After some researches, I found [this library (mysql-backup4j)](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.smattme/mysql-backup4j/1.2.1/jar) and did this code :

*EXPORT FUNCTION :*

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty(MysqlExportService.DB_NAME, "DATABASE_NAME");
properties.setProperty(MysqlExportService.DB_USERNAME, "DATABASE_USERNAME");
properties.setProperty(MysqlExportService.DB_PASSWORD, "DATABASE_PWD");

properties.setProperty(MysqlExportService.TEMP_DIR, new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\database_dump").getAbsolutePath());
properties.setProperty(MysqlExportService.PRESERVE_GENERATED_ZIP, "true");
MysqlExportService mysqlExportService = new MysqlExportService(properties); mysqlExportService.export();
```

*IMPORT FUNCTION (the user chooses the SQL file) :*

```
FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();

List<String> sqlExtensions = new ArrayList<>(List.of("*.sql", "*.SQL"));
fc.getExtensionFilters().add(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Fichier SQL", sqlExtensions));

File f = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
if (f != null) {
        System.out.println("database path : " + f.getAbsolutePath());
        String sql = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(f.getAbsolutePath())));
        boolean res = MysqlImportService.builder()
                    .setDatabase("DATABASE_NAME").setSqlString(sql)
                    .setUsername("DATABASE_USERNAME").setPassword("DATABASE_PWD").setDeleteExisting(true)
                    .setDropExisting(true)
                    .importDatabase();
}
```

P.S.: I am using JavaFX for the GUI with JDK11.

Reference : [How to backup your MySQL database programmatically using mysql-backup4j](https://medium.com/free-code-camp/how-to-backup-mysql-database-programmatically-using-mysql-backup4j-2b53a1cbf9b2)