# importing sql file to mysql programmatically from a CloudBees deployed Java app

Tags: mysql, cloudbees

What is the best way to import a full `.sql` file (with DDL and DML sentences) to a mysql database from a Java application deployed in CloudBees?

Should I try to get the Runtime process and see if something like this works

```
  Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
  Process pr = rt.exec("mysql -p -h ServerName DbName < dump.sql");
```

(recommended solution [in a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955268/importing-a-mysql-database-dump-programmatically-through-java) for a self-hosted environment, not sure if in a CloudBees hosted application I can execute process that access mysql)?

Is there a better solution? (again, to execute it from within the application, the `.sql` file to import will be provided by the user as part of his interaction with the web application).

I´d really like to avoid parsing the `.sql` file and sending the sentences one by one through jdbc.

Comment: To provide more info, so far all my attempts to get the runtime context and use it to execute mysql (or mysqldump for the export part) have failed (though they work just fine in my local installation)

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this myself, but [Flyway](http://flywaydb.org/) seems like it would let you import your SQL file during initialization of your app on CloudBees.

Flyway is an attempt to bring the popular Ruby concept of [database migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) to Java.  Flyway will let you place your .sql files inside the classpath of your app, and you can then use some Java code to update your database as needed.

Based on their [migration docs](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/migration/migrationSql.html), you should be able to place your .sql file as a file named V1__Initial_version.sql into a /db/migration/ directory on your classpath. You would then use something like the [following code](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/api.html) to trigger the migration when the app starts:

```
import com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway;
...

Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
flyway.setDataSource(...);
flyway.migrate();
```

I noticed that the [Flyway FAQ](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/faq.html#Can_multiple_nodes_migrate_in_parallel?) explains that the database is locked during migrations, so this approach should work even if you scale out your application on CloudBees to use more than one instance (very nice!!).

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try I guess. mysql cmd tools may or may not be on host. If they aren't we can probably add them.

The other option would be using a Jenkins job to do it. You could expose an api that jenkins calls and loads the database.

Comment: It looks like it´s not possible to call mysql (or mysqldump for the export part) from the runtime context. I manage to write the file I want to import in the temp folder of the app but when I try to execute mysql I get a Cannot run program "mysql" exception