# Import a Database

Tags: mysql, database, dreamweaver, cpanel

I have a .sql file exported from a myphpadmin of a server. I want to use it on another server on which I don't have cPanel access.

I have the db name, db username, db password but no HostName.

I used Dreamweaver to connect and it was successful. But what should I do next?

Please help.

Comment: Seriously? That's the best edit version you could select?

Comment: Usually server for Cpanel hosting accounts it's same host (localhost)
Can you try to connect to server with name or ip of new cpanel account.
Cpanel's must be first to create a user with permission for this database, and after gtant privileges for your IP, IP range or for all IP's (such 195.233.222.22, 195.233.222.%, %.%.%.%)
After this try to connect with a program for work with MySQL such https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html MySQlAdministrator

Answer (score 0):

Wait, you don't have the "host"? So how are you connecting through Dreamweaver?

If this DB user has proper permissions to perform such task, you can try to do it programatically, check this question:
[Importing a (mysql) database dump programmatically through Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955268/importing-a-mysql-database-dump-programmatically-through-java)