# Failed to execute mysql command through java Runtime or ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, mysql, shell

May be turned out to be a silly problem.
Here is the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        String command = "mysql -hlocalhost -uroot -padmin < ./scripts/atestscript.sql";
//      command = "cat < ./scripts/atestscript.sql";
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);


        InputStream inputstream = p.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader(inputstream);
        BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader);

        // read the output
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        p.waitFor();
    }
}
```

When I run this program to execute the sql script on MySQL, I just only got the output showing the usage information about *mysql* command, as following:
    mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.44, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3
    Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

```
Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Usage: mysql [OPTIONS] [database]
  -?, --help          Display this help and exit.
  -I, --help          Synonym for -?
  --auto-rehash       Enable automatic rehashing. One doesn't need to use
                      'rehash' to get table and field completion, but startup
                      and reconnecting may take a longer time. Disable with
                      --disable-auto-rehash.
                      (Defaults to on; use --skip-auto-rehash to disable.)
```

The command `mysql -h localhost -u root -p admin < ./scripts/atestscript.sql` runs perfectly when execute directly through the command line. What is wrong with the program when executing the command by folking a shell process?

I then tried the command `mysql -h localhost -u root -p admin -e "source ./scripts/atestscript.sql"` in the program, it doesn't work neither.

I also tried using ProcessBuilder by replacing `Runtime.getRuntime.exec(command)` by the following code:

```
        List<String> params = new ArrayList<String>();
        params.add("/usr/bin/mysql");
        params.add("-hlocalhost");
        params.add("-u" + username);
        params.add("-p" + password);
//      params.add("-e");
//      params.add("\"SOURCE " + filePath + "\"");
        params.add("<");
        params.add(filePath);

        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(params);
        Process p = pb.redirectErrorStream(true).start();
        int state = p.waitFor();
```

doesn't work too.

Maybe I just made some tiny mistakes in the program, but I was really stucked on it. Anyone has an idea on the problem?

Comment: no space between `-hlocalhost`, `"-u" + username`, `"-p" + password` could be the issue. Do a display of `params` before you are calling ProcessBuilder.. Also, hope you know complexity of what you trying to do..

Comment: Java won't automatically do redirection. the "<" is not a parameter, it needs to be interpreted by the shell

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955268/importing-a-mysql-database-dump-programmatically-through-java    ?

Comment: @redflar3 Yeah I did in my real code. The space is not an issue if the command is written in a string as a whole. But if the params is seperated feed into a ProcessBuilder like the way I did in the last block of code in my question, then the space is really an issue. no space should be placed right after -p in params.add("-p" + password). Or the access will fail. For the complexity of what I am trying to do, I admit that it's really annoying to dump a database in this way. But I have to do it programmatically as the project requires.

Comment: @JessBalint Yeah, redirect command should not be used as parameter seperately in this way. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use ProcessBuilder with params `sh`, `-c` and `mysql -hlocalhost -uroot -padmin < ./scripts/atestscript.sql`. Do not forget about quotes on 3rd param.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot for this alternative. In fact I put `params.add("mysql -hsomehost -uroot -padmin < ./scripts/xxx.sql"); `. Wrap the command in quotes with using params.add() doesn't work.

Comment: OK, I'll fix my answer. BTW, passing user and password isn't too safe. I would prefer using appropriate mysql config file.

Comment: yeah, thx. In fact the code I gaven is just for demonstrating the problem which was simplified. :)