# Run a postgresql function in Play! framework

Tags: scala, playframework-2.2, postgresql-9.3

I want to create some `Postgresql` (9.3) functions like `"upsert"` for my application in `Play! Scala 2.2`. I have tested one of them in the console and it worked great, but when I add it to evolutions (`1.sql` file) I get an error :

`unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$$`.

(I can show you the function but I'm not sure that it will help since I'm sure that the function is valid.)

I tried to end my function by ";;" instead of ";" as mentioned here : [a similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15236788/how-do-i-create-a-function-in-postgresql-using-evolutions-in-the-play-framework)
but without result.

So I'm asking you, **what is the standard way to run SQL functions in Play ?**

By the way, I will have several postgresql functions and it won't be clear if I let all of them in the `1.sql` file, so is there a way to write them in other files ?

Comment: Which DB lib are you using? Slick? Anorm? Ebean?

Comment: I'm using Anorm but (I think that) it doesn't change anything since the function is executed in my evolution file and the error comes at the compilation time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution: as mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15236788/how-do-i-create-a-function-in-postgresql-using-evolutions-in-the-play-framework?lq=1), you need to replace ";" by ";;" but not only at the end of the function but for every ";".