# postgres create trigger function error: Unterminated dollar quote Expected terminating $$ in db schema evolution

Tags: postgresql, triggers, playframework

Tried to create a trigger function in postgres 11.

```
CREATE FUNCTION task_state_change_stamp() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $task_state_change_stamp$
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.task_id = OLD.task_id AND NEW.state_id != OLD.state_id THEN
        INSERT INTO workflow.review_task_audit (task_id, old_state_id, new_state_id, last_updated_ts) VALUES (NEW.task_id, OLD.state_id, NEW.state_id, now());
        END IF;
        RETURN NULL;
    END;
$task_state_change_stamp$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I pasted the snippet into psql interpreter that connects to postgres, and can successfully created the function.

However, as I embed the snippet as part of db schema evolution (I am using the java Play framework), it throws an error:

```
23:38:18 {"@timestamp":"2022-08-08T06:38:18.959Z","@version":"1","message":"Unterminated dollar quote started at position 61 in SQL CREATE FUNCTION task_state_change_stamp() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $task_state_change_stamp$\nBEGIN\nIF NEW.task_id = OLD.task_id AND NEW.state_id != OLD.state_id THEN\nINSERT INTO workflow.review_task_audit (task_id, old_state_id, new_state_id, last_updated_ts) VALUES (NEW.task_id, OLD.state_id, NEW.state_id, now()). Expected terminating $$ [ERROR:0, SQLSTATE:42601]","logger_name":"play.api.db.evolutions.DefaultEvolutionsApi","thread_name":"pool-1-thread-1","level":"ERROR","level_value":40000}
```

How can I resolve the issue to evolve the DB schema?

Comment: Try using $$ instead of $task_state_change_stamp$

Comment: Apparently that framework doesn't understand dollar quoting. You will need to enclose the function body in single quotes `as '...' language plpgsql;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some googling, I found a similar issue [How do I create a function in PostgreSQL using evolutions in the Play framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15236788/how-do-i-create-a-function-in-postgresql-using-evolutions-in-the-play-framework)

Based on that answer, the snippet below works.

```
CREATE FUNCTION task_state_change_stamp() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.task_id = OLD.task_id AND NEW.state_id != OLD.state_id THEN
        INSERT INTO workflow.review_task_audit (task_id, old_state_id, new_state_id, last_updated_ts) VALUES (NEW.task_id, OLD.state_id, NEW.state_id, now());;
        END IF;;
        RETURN NULL;;
    END;;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had pretty same problem with creating next procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_cool_procedure(
    OUT data refcursor)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$

BEGIN
    POSTABLE_VISITS := 'cssuser_p_get_postable_reviews';
    OPEN POSTABLE_VISITS FOR
        SELECT 8;
END;
$BODY$;
```

And I fixed it with replacing END and $BODY$

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_cool_procedure(
    OUT data refcursor)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$

BEGIN
    POSTABLE_VISITS := 'cssuser_p_get_postable_reviews';
    OPEN POSTABLE_VISITS FOR
        SELECT 8;
$BODY$;
END;
```