# Liquibase error [Postgresql]: unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$BODY$

Tags: java, postgresql, plpgsql, liquibase

```
Liquibase error: unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$BODY$`
```

Chaneg log xml has one entry: see below
include file="/home/dev/....../admin_script.sql"

content of the file:

```
...............
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_schema.function-name()
RETURNS smallint AS
$BODY$
   DECLARE
      v_next_gen_id smallint := 0;
   BEGIN
..........
```

Exception:

```
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function name()
ETURNS smallint AS
$BODY$
   DECLARE
      v_next_gen_id smallint := 0: ERROR: unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$BODY$
```

Appreciate any help to resolve  this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR: unterminated quoted string at or near](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499483/error-unterminated-quoted-string-at-or-near)

Answer (score 42):

I just encountered the same issue days ago.

It does not work if we add the changeset into changelog.xml file using the format below:
`<include file="path/to/sqlfile" />`

To work around, I use another format:

```
<changeSet author="authour_name" id="your_id">
    <sqlFile path="path/to/sqlfile" splitStatements="false"/>
</changeSet>
```

Here is the link which gives a brief explanation to [Problem with dollar-quoted-in-postgresql](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/Pine.BSO.4.56.0409141340180.27@leary.csoft.net).

Comment: In case you don't want to define an absolute path to your sql script file, you can use attribute: `relativeToChangelogFile="true"`

Comment: So the key point is having splitStatements="false", why do I even need to split statements. False should be default.

Comment: "splitStatements": false in Liquibase's changelog can help avoid issues with unterminated dollar quotes or other syntax errors in SQL statements, by allowing Liquibase to read the entire statement as a single unit instead of splitting it into separate statements based on semicolons. This can be particularly useful for complex SQL statements or stored procedures that use advanced features like dollar-quoted strings or nested statements.

Answer (score 26):

The solution below is from [official Liquibase forum](https://forum.liquibase.org/t/unterminated-dollar-quote-started/4553/3).

If you want to use SQL changelog fully, this solution works fine (tested and confirmed):

**If you are using SQL Changelog file then you can replace `$` Sign with Single Quote and Single Quote with double Single Quote `''`**

So to elaborate:

1. `$` will be `'`
2. `$BODY$` will be `'`
3. `'` will be `''`

Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.testingfunctions()
RETURNS TABLE("DistributorCode" character varying)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS '
begin
    RETURN QUERY
    select * from testtable;
    
    -- .
    -- .
    -- . somewhere in the function
    RAISE NOTICE ''OPEN deleted customer_avatar'';
END;'
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. See https://forum.liquibase.org/t/unterminated-dollar-quote-started/4553/3

Comment: What is the reason why this works?

Comment: @danbtl It seems its related with dollar-quoting when we are talking about postgresql. For some kind of reason using $$/$BODY$ does not work properly with liquibase (im not sure are they preprocessing anything before feeding sql into the database)

Comment: Thanks for that solution works fine! One word of caution if you just do search & replace ```LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'``` can also have single quotes and e.g. ```DEFAULT ''::character``` in the header. so the `3.` above only applies to the PLPGSQL/SQL block between the BEGIN & END ;)

Answer (score 18):

Use [`<createProcedure>`](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/create_procedure.html) tag instead of `<sql>` in your `<changeSet>` definition

Comment: Can explain why your solution works in order raise the value of your contribution?

Answer (score 14):

Add `splitStatements:false` to changeset

Like this `--changeset splitStatements:false`

Comment: This works for the change but not for the rollback.

Answer (score 2):

You can set splitStatements attribute to false to avoid this error

```
<changeSet author="authour_name" id="your_id">
    <sql splitStatements="false">
    ...
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered similar error while using [sql-maven-plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/sql-maven-plugin/dependency-info.html). Adding below attributes fixed the issue

```
<execution>
    ...
    <configuration>
        ...
        <delimiter>/</delimiter>
        <delimiterType>normal</delimiterType>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should understand why this happened. The typical anonynous plsql-block contains many semicolons. Each semicolon by default is recognized by liquibase as a delimiter of a different SQL-statement in one transaction.

So, the database received 1-st query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_schema.function-name()
  RETURNS smallint AS
  $BODY$
  DECLARE
    v_next_gen_id smallint := 0
```

This statement has no closing $BODY$ token. And we have an exception from DB.

The right way is setup changeset do not split statement by any delimiter. Just set **splitStatements** flag in chageset declaration. For example:

```
--liquibase formatted sql
--changeset Author-BB:20231101-001 failOnError:true splitStatements:false
```

Answer (score 1):

I have postgresSQL15 in my system and running trigger with liquibase sql script

`Table name:  test`

`Table name history: test_history`

1:- Create you history table

--changeset praveen.singh:1

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_history
(
    id serial primary key,
    original_test_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    operation VARCHAR(10),
    change_timestamp TIMESTAMP without time zone DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  
    dummy_data VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
);
```

--rollback drop table test_history;

--changeset praveen.singh:2 failOnError:true splitStatements:false

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_history_trigger()
RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
    IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
        INSERT INTO test_history (original_test_id, operation, change_timestamp, dummy_data)
        VALUES (OLD.id, 'UPDATE', NOW(), OLD. dummy_data);
    ELSIF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
        INSERT INTO test_history (original_test_id, operation, change_timestamp, dummy_data)
        VALUES (OLD.id, 'DELETE', NOW(), OLD. dummy_data);
    END IF;
    IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
        RETURN NEW;
    ELSIF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
        RETURN OLD;
    END IF;
END;
$$;


CREATE TRIGGER test_history_trigger
AFTER UPDATE OR DELETE
ON test
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION test_history_trigger();
```

2:- Run command liquibase

**mvn liquibase:update -Dusername=<USER_NAME> -Dpassword= -Durl='jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/<DB_NAME>?currentSchema=<SCHEMA_NAME>'**

Hope it will work for you all!!!

Comment: The `--changeset [...] splitStatements:false` is the key here which will allow `$$` or `$BODY$` to be used as delimiters. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72526042/4368898) already mentioned that though.

Answer (score 0):

If your are using SQL Changelog file then you can replace $ Sign with Single Quote and Single Quote with double Single Quote ''

Answer (score -3):

I had the same error. Replacing the `$function$` and `$body$` with `$$` solved the problem.