# Liquibase : unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near $BODY$

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

Hi I'm struggling with the issue from the topic. I have the following changeset:

```
 <changeSet author="artur" id="storedProcedures-0003">

        <sqlFile dbms="postgresql"
                 encoding="utf8"
                 path="server/sql/storedProcedures/postgresql/procedure.sql"
                 relativeToChangelogFile="true"
                 splitStatements="false"
        />
    </changeSet>
```

My procedure is :

```
CREATE FUNCTION testProc(oRefCursor          OUT  REFCURSOR)

AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    minLevel        INTEGER;
    defDcId         DECIMAL(19);
BEGIN

END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This procedure works fine with pgAdmin tool, but in liquibase i always got the error. I was trying to find and answer but nor [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35907660/3153769%22this%22) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21992046/3153769) works for me. I have this procedure in seprate file, I use a `splitStatements="false"` but nothing helps. I always get this error. Does anyone know a workaround for this issue (is this Liquibase issue ?). I was trying to write this in one line, i was trying use a slashes but without success.

Comment: Which Liquibase version?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  Liquibase 3.5.3

Answer (score 3):

A very good workaround for liquibase is to use a different delimiter. My personal choice is just double semicolon.

```
CREATE FUNCTION exampleFunction()
AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    SELECT 1;
END;
$BODY$ 
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;;
```

```
<changeSet id="1" author="author">
    <sqlFile path="example.sql" endDelimiter=";;"/>
</changeSet>
```

Comment: Worked for me. A bit silly - but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

I found what was the reason of that behaviour. In my project there was hardcoded some old version of postgresql driver. I've switched to the newest one (42.1.3) and now everything is fine. I mean fine, but still in Liquibase I need to use workaround with procedure sql in separate file which I described in my question