# How to execute a set of related SQL instructions with JDBC?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I'm trying to execute this script through JDBC (it's SQL Server):

```
DECLARE @var VARCHAR(10)
SET @var = "test"
INSERT INTO foo (name) VALUES (@var)
```

It's just an example, in my business case I have a big collection of SQL statements in one script.

I'm trying this:

```
final Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
for (String sql : lines) {
  stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
}
stmt.close();
```

SQL Server is saying on the second line:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Must declare the scalar variable "@var".
```

Looks like I'm doing something wrong...

Comment: Why don't you create stored procedures and call them instead?

Comment: This is a possible workaround, yes. But I'm trying to find a way to do this without the stored procedure.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044194/running-a-sql-script-using-mysql-with-jdbc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're executing it one line at a time, so of course the second line fails as it depends on the first line.  Why not execute it all at once?...