# How to use java to execute some 'source' commands in mysql?

Tags: java, mysql

I have a large number of source commands to execute. So I want to write some Java code to do this. Is there a way to do this in Java?

source command is like this:

```
 mysql> source /home/liova/download/tpch/queries/Q1.sql;
```

Comment: Not able to understand. What type of source command you cant to say ?

Comment: @BhavikAmbani, thanks for bringing this out. I've added some details.

Comment: I think you should find this post interesting:[Stack Overflow Run SQL Script with MySQL][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044194/running-a-sql-script-using-mysql-with-jdbc

Comment: Then I think `Runtime.exec()` will work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute any shell command using [Runtime.exec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29):

```
Runtime.exec("mysql db_name < /home/liova/download/tpch/queries/Q1.sql");
```

Comment: By the way, can I record the time needed for this query?

Comment: Sure, using plain old `System.currentTimeMillis()` before and after.

Comment: You can make it block using `waitFor()`. Just be aware of the pitfalls: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=4

Answer (score 0):

You can use Runtime class to execute any commands in java. It executes the command as seperate process.