# Execute SQL script file with java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have a file called `scripts.sql` which contains a huge amount of sql queries, here is the first few lines of the file:

```
alter table companies change ...... ;
insert into addresses values (.....);
update users set blabla = 'blabla'......;
```

I want to know if in some way I can execute all the queries in this file with java.

I am using MySQL database.

Comment: Read file line by line and execute it. Only if you are sure queries wrote in single line.

Comment: Nope, they could be on multiple lines.

Comment: I would look at something like http://flywaydb.org/. Not only will it run your DB scripts it will also keep track of which scripts have already been run.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ibatis runner to execute a sql script file. It's explained here [Running SQL files scripts from a Java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14431692/running-sql-files-scripts-from-a-java-program)

I hope this wil help