# Quarkus tests with equivalent of spring @Sql annotation

Tags: unit-testing, quarkus

I'm trying to move Spring Boot app to Quarkus. In tests we have @Sql annotations which are called before / after particular @Test method. Is there anything what resembles this functionality in Quarkus? All I can find are examples of creating whole database before tests, but what I want is to be able to insert / delete records to / from db before / after each test method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, we don't have that feature in Quarkus yet.

I wrote a JUnit5 Extension which uses Flyway to do exactly that. Please check: https://github.com/radcortez/flyway-junit5-extensions and the Quarkus example: https://github.com/radcortez/flyway-junit5-extensions/tree/master/examples/quarkus

Comment: Thanks for the answer, for now I'm thinking in direction of writing util class which executes sql scripts and call it manually: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936956/jpa-entity-manager-how-to-run-sql-script-file