# How to execute sql script with PostgreSQL specific features in Java

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have a project with a large number of `.sql` files which create a database. We use it when we onboard a new person or add a new client. The sql files use the PostgreSQL \i command to call each other, so we normally just call the `psql` command to run the `startup.sql` file and it runs all the rest.

I need to call the `startup.sql` file from a java program.

I tried using JDBC, but it doesn't accept the `\` character so it fails to execute when it reaches `\i`. I thought using the PgConnection extension would let me get around the restriction of JDBC but it still fails.

```
PgConnection connection = (PgConnection) DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, username, password);
connection.createStatement().execute("\\i ./db_init/startup.sql"); // fails on syntax error at or near "\"
connection.execSQLQuery("\\i ./db_init/startup.sql"); // fails on syntax error at or near "\"
```

I have also looked into using a `Process` to run the `psql` command line tool but it hangs. I think because it requests the user's password, but that prompt isn't passed back to the terminal running the java program there is no way to enter the password. Perhaps I could figure out how to wire the input and output up but when I looked into it that seemed pretty complicated. I would prefer to connect directly to the database anyways, rather than having java execute an external program.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running a .sql script using MySQL with JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044194/running-a-sql-script-using-mysql-with-jdbc)

Comment: *\i* is not a Postgres server command it is a meta-command understood only by the client `psql`. I would think that opening the file in Java and executing each command is the way to go.

Comment: Ah, that explains a lot @AdrianKlaver.

Comment: Why not just run psql from java as a process? or is psql not available?

Comment: @siggemannen I would have to figure out how to provide input to psql after it was run. When I run the psql command it immediately prompts for password, there isn't a way to pass the password with the original command as an argument or anything. I'm sure there is a way I could give it the password but it would take more research. In any case my boss has asked me to do it a different way now.

Comment: Perhaps it's better just to convert scripts to something runnable

Answer (score 0):

The specific thing I'm trying to do is not possible because as @AdrianKlaver commented, `\i` is not a postgres server command, but rather a command specifically for the `psql` command line tool. Therefore I would either have to parse and run each command myself, loading the `\i` referenced files recursively, or find a way to run the `psql` tool and provide the password to it.

I would suggest that this issue and answer are specific and useful enough to persist on this forum because I spent 6 hours searching for how to do this and did not find the vital information provided by @AdrianKlaver anywhere.

Comment: Using DuckDuckGo and the search phrase *postgresql \i* gave me in the second result [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) which has section *Meta-Commands* where they are all laid out.

Comment: If only I knew they were called meta-commands, or just had the patience to read that far down the page. I got my degree in game development... now here I am doing full stack web development, learning on the spot.

Very helpful link though. I'll spend some more time checking that out.

Comment: In browser Ctrl+F then *\i*. Altogether significantly < 6 hours.

Comment: If only I was that smart. This is why I never use stack overflow. I spend hours trying to solve a problem only to come here and be told that if only I was smart enough to solve the problem then I could have solved the problem.